# How to replace nested if statements with switch statements?

Tags: java, list, if-statement, linked-list, switch-statement

The reason for why I want to use `switch` statements is to replace the `if` statement because the `if` statement is too long, but how can I replace nested `if` statement with a `switch`?

The algorithm is like this:

```
if(a very long statement are similar,except the string at the middle)
func1(parameters are same as func1,test1);
if(a very long statement are similar,except the string at the middle)
func2(parameter are same as func1,test2);
.
.
.
if(a very long statement are similar,except the string at the middle)
func16(parameter are same as func1,test16);
```

I did the following but there are errors:

```
//List initialization...
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (statement with list[i] == true) {
        switch (list[i]) {
            case "test1":
                func1(parameter1,test1);
            case "test2":
                enter code here
                func2(parameter1,test2);
            case "test3":
                func3(parameter1,test3);

            .
            .
            .
           case "test16":
           func16(parameter1,test16);
        }
    }
}
```

And I am using Java. Can anyone give me some suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please format your code and add the `Java` tag. You may post your if-condition code to get more suggestions. Basically, if I understand you correctly, I would just set the common part of the if-statements to a new boolean variable and use that variable in the if-statements.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,I think boolean may not work in this situation.(because too many if)But i would tried other.Thanks.

Comment: Missing `break;` at end of case statements?

Comment: but break only applicable on the situation for if and else if?

Comment: No, `case 1: case 2: System.out.println("1 or 2");` So `break` exits the enclosing `switches }`.

Comment: I'm not a fan of switch cases. I would just wrap the "very long statement" in one or many conveniently named methods. As for the "except the string in the middle" part, perhaps you could solve that by sending in a lambda or similar?

Comment: but my situation is :

case 1 :
one statement
case 2:
one statement

If I used your appoarch,but I still not get how can I do?

Comment: re Joakim : okay,I will see tutorial of lambda,thanks for your suggest.

Comment: Can you please explain what your `if` statements do? Then I can say how you can implement it as a `switch`

Comment: re Lakshya:    the if statement are similar like these,but surely it 's much longer :

if(obj("test1")!=null)
func1(param1,test1);
if(obj("test2")!=null)
func2(param1,test2);

somethings similar like these.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation like this, I tend to embrace the strategy pattern, and create one strategy per if branch. The interface could look something like this:

```
interface Strategy{
    boolean accepts(String value);
    void process(String value);
}
```

and you can use it something like this:

```
List<Strategy> strategies = // initialize your strategies

list.forEach((item) -> {
  strategies.stream()
    .filter((s) -> s.accepts(item)) // find the appropriate strategy
    .findFirst()                    // if we found it
    .ifPresent(strategy -> strategy.process(item)); // apply it
    // or use .getOrElseThrow to fail fast if no strategy can be found
});
```

The nice thing about this is that each strategy is individually maintainable and testable. Also: if you have similar code in different branches, you can use a common super class.

Obviously, this can be optimized. If you know up front what strings you are expecting, you can store the strategies in a HashMap. If you just have a vague idea, perhaps a TreeMap can help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but the thing that I want to do is make the program easier to debug and make more clear to understand such as switch.Or maybe I look forward tutorial of treemap .Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your individual branches. If they are trivial, go with the switch. If not, this will make your code more understandable and maintainable. And don't forget to write those tests.

Comment: Ok,I would.Thanks.